# what is this warning from VirtualizedList in react native I get?

Tags: react-native, expo, warnings, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I build an app with react native expo and I have 2 tabs (home & search) and 1 flatList who get data from youtube api (for rendering youtube videos) and everytime I switch between the tabs I get this msg:

```
VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. {"contentLength": 4189, "dt": 2672, "prevDt": 775}
```

Everything I did its still tell me this msg.

I tried to use react.memo/useCallback and I still get this msg

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.